# Unsolicited opt-out from data brokers

Tags: phishing

I received several automated emails at an early hour from several data brokers (e.g., Spokeo) asking me to confirm an opt-out for my email address and name.  I did not request these, but did so about 2 years ago from most data brokers, and accidentally clicked on one of the links.  The originating email address as well as the domain/IP from the email server look legitimate and the links go to the appropriate domain.

I am somewhat concerned because it happened within a short period on several brokers that ostensibly are separately owned, suggesting a human may have done this manually.  On the other hand, it seems more strange the malicious.  Is there any reason a malicious third party might be doing this?

Comment: What personal information did they ask for / did you provide in response to the email?

Comment: Nothing other than clicking on  a clickback link to confirm the opt out

Comment: Run a virus scan?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Phishing email from Avast - Headers look totally legit?](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/82428/phishing-email-from-avast-headers-look-totally-legit)

Comment: Did you sign up with some kind of unsubscribing service?  Or did you make an enemy of someone who entered your email into an unsubscribing service; perhaps an ex-someone?

Answer (score 1):

## Theory

Maybe - and this is a fat maybe - someone is trying to desensitize you to clicking on opt-out links so that you get *trained* to click through any link you get for protecting your privacy.

## What do you do?

Nothing. If you didn't request the email, then don't click it.

## What's the threat of clicking on a link? (and how do you protect yourself)

1. someone could try to exploit vulnerabilities.

   - patch your browser
   - turn off javascript
   - don't click on unknown links
2. You could fill out a form and give away information

   - don't do that.
   - Type in the url for the site you want to login to.
   - check the certificate, etc.
3. If you didn't request the email, then don't click it.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a possibility that a spammer may trick you into clicking an "opt-out" link just to confirm that the e-mail address is valid (and can be abused in the future).